# How do I add/upload pictures into my Overleaf document?

Tags: external-files, overleaf

How do I get pictures into my LaTeX paper I did on line in Overleaf? It says I need to make a new file? I have the pics in a folder as JPG but how do I upload them into the paper?

Answer (score 4):

[image: screenshot]

In the `Project` tab, use `Add files...`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Overleaf's premium plan, you can integrate your Dropbox with it. Then whatever you upload in Apps/Overleaf/Your_project_name_on_overleaf will appear on Overleaf. You may have to click on the sync button though.

[image: get to over leaf menu]

[image: Dropbox Sync button]

[image]
Sometimes, things fail to happen automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Overleaf's premium plan, you can integrate your Github with it. Then whatever you upload in the Github project will appear on Overleaf. You have to click on the sync button though.

[image: get to overleaf menu]

[image: github option]

[image: github status]

To work the other way: If you add a file in Overleaf and want to see it in  GitHub.

- Add the file in overleaf as [usual way 1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/239845/129388) or [dropbox answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/609741/129388)
- Follow the above steps to get to the Github menu.
- You can then add a
  commit

[image: add commit]
and refresh by clicking on *Push Overleaf changes to Github*
[image: refresh]